# Modulo of negative numbers with squares

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to find $10^{11} \mod 101$. Here's what I did:

[image] $\pmod{101}$

However, the calculator shows that $10^{11}\equiv91\pmod{101}$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Fractionary exponents are not defined in $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$. They only make sense in $\mathbf R$.

Comment: @Bernard They don't really make sense for $\Bbb R$ either. They only make sense for $\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: As a concept, they *make sense* for $\mathbf R$, but they *exist* only for non-negative real numbers.

Comment: @Bernard No, in $\Bbb R$, they do not make sense, any more than they do for $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. For instance, $25^{1/2}$ is both $5$ and $-5$. Only when you restrict yourself to non-negative reals do fractional exponents make sense.

Comment: Fractionary exponents denote the positive square root, conventionally.

Comment: @Bernard Which is the same as saying that when defining fractional exponents, we do it within $\Bbb R_{\geq0}$, not all of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

You should've gone with $10^{11} = 100^5\cdot 10$ to make it clearer. However, now that you've come this far, note that the square roots of $100$ are $\pm 10$. You chose the wrong square root in your last step.

Answer (score 0):

${\rm mod}\,\ 101\!:\ 10^{\large 11}\!\equiv 10(\color{#c00}{10^{\large 2}})^{\large 5}\!\equiv 10(\color{#c00}{\bf-1})^{\large 5} \equiv -10 \equiv 91$

**Remark** $\ $ The problem with your method is that you tried to use $\, n\equiv (n^{\large 2})^{\large 1/2},\, $ which is not true here, e.g. for $\, n\equiv 91\,$ your method gives $\ 91\equiv {-}10\equiv ((-10)^{\large 2})^{\large 1/2}\equiv 100^{\large 1/2}\equiv 10.\,$ Generally you can use that identity only in domains where squaring is injective $(1$-$1)$.